# Arabic fonts compatible with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, line-spacing, brackets, arabic

I need to change the Arabic font for some text in my document, how can I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp 1256]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\Vocalize
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\centering
بِسْم*ِ الله*ِ الرَّحْمن*ِ الرَّحيم*ِ\\
(يَرْفَع*ِ الله*ُ الَّذِين*َ آمَنُوا مِنكُم*ْ وَ الَّذِين*َ أُوتُوا اْلعِلْم*َ دَرَجَات*ٍ)\\ % for example I want to change font and size for this line
صَدَق*َ الله*ُ الْعَلِي*ُ الْعَظِيْم*ُ\\
\end{document}
```

how can I change the style of the bracket? 
also, how can I increase the space between the lines?

Comment: Take a look at [arabi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arabi) manual page 50 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. We can use `\textcmd{...}` or `\cmd` where cmd is for example 
`thol` for `Tholuth` font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp 1256]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\Vocalize
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\centering
بِسْم*ِ الله*ِ الرَّحْمن*ِ الرَّحيم*ِ\\
(يَرْفَع*ِ الله*ُ الَّذِين*َ آمَنُوا مِنكُم*ْ وَ الَّذِين*َ أُوتُوا اْلعِلْم*َ دَرَجَات*ٍ)\\ % for example I want to change font and size for this line
صَدَق*َ الله*ُ الْعَلِي*ُ الْعَظِيْم*ُ\\


\thol
بِسْم*ِ الله*ِ الرَّحْمن*ِ الرَّحيم*ِ\\
(يَرْفَع*ِ الله*ُ الَّذِين*َ آمَنُوا مِنكُم*ْ وَ الَّذِين*َ أُوتُوا اْلعِلْم*َ دَرَجَات*ٍ)\\ % for example I want to change font and size for this line
صَدَق*َ الله*ُ الْعَلِي*ُ الْعَظِيْم*ُ\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, if I want to change the space between the lines what should I do?

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/820/71471