# Line spacing - equivalent to MS Word 1.5 spacing

Tags: spacing, line

I am writing my thesis, somewhere towards the end of it, but also the time is tight, so I'd appreciate some help. I have to use 1.5 line spacing. However, I read somewhere that \onehalfspacing of the \usepackage{setspace} package does not correspond to MS Word 1,5. If that is so, how do I resolve this problem? Also, is it possible to have a different line spacing for the title, subtitle, chapters, subsections titles etc? As it is now, those are too wide. Thank you very much!

Comment: not sure of what may be best to hold at 1.5 x line space but many alternative choices at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "However, I read somewhere that `\onehalfspacing` of the [`setspace`] package does not correspond to `MS Word 1,5`." Don't use `\onehalfspacing`; instead, use `\setstretch{1.5}`.

Comment: Crosspost: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=108892#p108892