# How to change line spacing to 1.15 lines?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, line

How do i change the line spacing of my entire document to 1.15 lines?

Comment: Welcome ... Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/120578

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/5764)

Comment: ...use [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace)'s `onehalfspacing`...