# citation appears as [?] and no bbl file + empty bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, texstudio

I'm using texStudio and natbib

i've tried running (after deleting aux and bbl files)
pdflatex test && bibtex test && pdflatex test && pdflatex test

But i still get the following error and nothing in my biblio section:

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}


blah blah blah [\cite{1}] blah blah


\setstretch{1.0}{
    
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{test}
\nocite{*}
}

\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

bib file entry

```
@Article{1,
    author = {names},
    title = {title},
    journal = {journal},
    year = {2021},
    OPTdoi = {doi.org},
}
```

The output is:

blah blah blah [?] blah blah

and the biblio page is completely empty

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: As posted the MWE fails for me because `\setstretch` is undefined. If I load a package that defines it (e.g. `\usepackage{setspace}`) the example compiles fine. You need to compile your file with BibTeX if you want to obtain citations. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. Did you make sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" stands for your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...)? If you run BibTeX it should produce a `.blg` file and console output, what do they say? Is `test.bib` your `.bib` file?

Comment: yes, I changed the \setstretch to \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} as was recommended, deleted my .aux file and ran the following: pdflatex test && bibtex test && pdflatex test && pdflatex test. I don't get an automated bbl file, my bibliosection is still empty, and citations in the document appear as [?]

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}` is recommended over `\setstretch`. I would remove `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`, would load `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` and keep using `\setstretch` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/35864). (Well, actually, I would simply never use onehalfspacing, but some times you don't have a choice ...). ...

Comment: ... But that is not the main issue here. Just to be sure: Your document is called `test.tex`. You first clean the `.aux` file. Then you run `pdflatex test && bibtex test && pdflatex test && pdflatex test` *without* cleaning any `.aux` files in between? Do you get any errors or warnings on any of those runs?

Comment: i don't get any errors but i get two warning messages: 1) no file test.bbl    and 2) there were undefined citations.

Comment: Interestingly, when i hover over my citation in my tex file, it gives a pop-up window with the correct citation. it just doesn't compile....

Comment: Can you run the four commands separately one after another and not in one big go? What does the BibTeX call produce? If you ran BibTeX there must be a `.blg` file: What does it say (Windows systems may classify `.blg` files as "performance monitor files" and hide the file extension, but they are simple text files you can inspect with every editor)? Did you enable a 'build directory' or moving of output files in your editor? If so, disable all those features, they confuse external tools like BibTeX.

Comment: Whether or not your editor shows auto-complete pop-ups for citations has nothing to do with how citations are resolved and the bibliography is produced by LaTeX and BibTeX.

Comment: i'm not using a windows machine... i'm on a linux system

Comment: Even more reason for there to be a `.blg` file if you ran BibTeX: Can you find it? It should be in the same folder as your main `.tex` file (`test.tex`).

Comment: Too many commas!!!!    
i have commas separating the authors names

Comment: Multiple authors *must* always be separated with an `and` in the `.bib` file regardless of the desired output. Commas are only used to separate name parts of the same name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864.

Comment: THANK YOU very much for your help! =)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the issue is caused by `\setstretch{1.0}`. A possible quick fix:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah [\cite{1}] blah blah

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{test}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... but it didn't work... 
i still get the same [?] and nothing in my biblio.... =/

and i still get a warning at the end saying, "nofile test.bbl"